# SQL query to count if multiple rows bounded by 2 rows with a bool flag true meet certain conditions

Tags: sql, presto

Say I have a large data set like this

```
row | id | flag | sequence | count |   text
...
...
1     abc  true     22         1       textA
2     abc  false    23         8       textB
3     abc  false    24         2       textZ
4     abc  true     25         1       textA

5     bdf  false    10         1       textA
6     bdf  true     11         1       textB
7     bdf  false    12         2       textA
8     bdf  false    13         4       textF
9     bdf  false    14         6       textZ
10    bdf  true     15         1       textA
...
20    dhg  true     5         4       textF
21    dhg  false    6         20       textZ
22    dhg  true     7         1       textA

...
...
```

All rows with the same id are guaranteed to be in incremental sequence.

Please help to write write a query to count as 1 if

1. multiple rows between 2 rows with true flag have at least 2 rows
2. and sum(count) of > 4.
3. and at least one of those row has textZ.

So in the above data set, rows 1-4 met the condition and should be counted as 1. rows 5-10 also met all the conditions so count is 2 now. Row 20-22 doesn't not meet the 2nd condition so count stays at 2. The output should be 2 for this query for the example above.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the results you want and try to better explain the logic.

Comment: edited, hope it's clearer

Comment: @Havenard bad copy and pasted. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can assign a grouping based on the number of `true` values before a given value:

```
select id, min(row), max(row)
from (select t.*,
             sum(flag = 'true') over (partition by id order by row) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where not flag
group by id, grp
having count(*) >= 2 and   -- the first "true" is included
       sum(count) > 4 and
       sum(text = 'textZ') > 0;
```

This doesn't actually check that the group ends with a `true`.  I'm not sure how important that is.

EDIT:

If you need the actual rows, then this gets a little more complicated but you can do it using window functions:

```
select id, min(row), max(row)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when flag <> 'true' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id, grp_desc) as cnt_false,
             sum(case when flag <> 'true' then count else 0 end) over (partition by id, grp_desc) as sum_count,
             sum(case when flag <> 'true' and text = 'textZ' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id, grp_desc) as cnt_textZ
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(flag = 'true') over (partition by id order by row) as grp_inc,
                   sum(flag = 'true') over (partition by id order by row desc) as grp_desc
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt_false >= 2 and
      sum_count > 4 and
      cnt_textZ > 0;
```

Note that both `group_inc` and `group_desc` define groups.  If you can live with just one "true" row, then `group_inc` includes the first, and `group_desc` includes the last one.

Comment: Correct but I also need a group end where flag = true too. Would you be able to update the SQL to account for group end too?

Comment: actually, I don't have row. it was just for illustration of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any "proper SQL" way of doing this, the problem just seems to be too complex to be done in the DBMS. Perhaps you should reconsider the design of your tables, to optimize this thing.

Luckily however, you are using MySQL, and MySQL being MySQL, brings a bunch of features of unorthodox nature and questionable forward compatibility, but regardless, can get the job done.

MySQL allows you to iterate through the table content while using control variables to "take notes" and make an algorithm of sorts while performing a SELECT.

As such, you could do something like this to select a list of ranges that match your criteria:

```
-- note: variables are hard-typed
SET @i = '', @c = 0, @m = 0, @s = 0;

SELECT 
  `id`,
  `start`,
  `end`
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    @s `start`,
    IF(`id` = @i AND `flag` AND @c >= 2 AND (`text` = 'TextZ' OR @m), `sequence`, 0) `end`,
    @s := IF(`flag`, `sequence`, IF(`id` <> @i, 0, @s)) `unused1`,
    @m := IF(`text` = 'TextZ', 1, IF(`flag`, 0, @m)) `unused2`,
    @c := IF(`id` = @i, IF(`flag`, 0, @c + 1), 0) `unused3`,
    @i := `id` `unused4`
  FROM `t`
) `a` WHERE `end` <> 0;
```

Here's a functioning example for you to test and fiddle around: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95f2b/3

And a query that selects the eligible ranges:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95f2b/6